# Why linux disables disk write buffer when system ram is greater than 8GB?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, disk

**Background:**

I was trying to setup a `ubuntu` machine on my desktop computer. The whole process took a whole day, including installing OS and softwares. I didn't thought much about it, though.

Then I tried doing my work using the new machine, and it was significantly slower than my laptop, which is very strange.

I did `iotop` and found that disk traffic when decompressing a package is around 1-2MB/s, and it's definitely abnormal.

Then, after hours of research, I found [this article](https://fhackts.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/very-slow-disk-write-performance-linux/) that describes exactly same problem, and provided a ugly solution:

> **We recently had a major performance issue on some systems, where disk write speed is extremely slow (~1 MB/s — where normal performance
>   is 150+MB/s).**
>
> ...
>
> *EDIT: to solve this, **either remove enough RAM, or add “mem=8G” as kernel boot parameter** (e.g. in /etc/default/grub on Ubuntu — don’t
>   forget to run update-grub !)*

I also looked at this post

https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/

and did

```
cat /proc/vmstat | egrep "dirty|writeback"
```

output is:

```
nr_dirty 10
nr_writeback 0
nr_writeback_temp 0  
nr_dirty_threshold 0  // and here
nr_dirty_background_threshold 0 // here
```

those values were `8223` and `4111` when `mem=8g` is set.

So, it's basically showing that **when system memory is greater than 8GB** (32GB in my case), regardless of  `vm.dirty_background_ratio` and `vm.dirty_ratio` settings, (5% and 10% in my case), the **actual dirty threshold goes to 0** and write buffer is disabled?

Why is this happening?

Is this a bug in the kernel or somewhere else?

Is there a solution other than unplugging RAM or using "mem=8g"?

**UPDATE:** I'm running 3.13.0-53-generic kernel with ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, so it's possible that this only happens on 32-bit systems.

Comment: When I run the cat/egrep above, I don't see zeroes.  This is on an AMD FX8150 running Ubuntu 14.04 with 16GB ram

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a 32 bit kernel with more than 2G of RAM, you are running in a sub-optimal configuration where significant tradeoffs must be made.  This is because in these configurations, the kernel can no longer map all of physical memory at once.

As the amount of physical memory increases beyond this point, the tradeoffs become worse and worse, because the `struct page` array that is used to manage all physical memory must be kept mapped at all times, and that array grows with physical memory.

The physical memory that isn't directly mapped by the kernel is called "highmem", and by default the writeback code treats highmem as undirtyable.  This is what results in your zero values for the dirty thresholds.

You can change this by setting `/proc/sys/vm/highmem_is_dirtyable` to 1, but with that much memory you will be far better off if you install a 64-bit kernel instead.

Comment: With `highmem_is_dirtyable==0`, those ratios should still be calculated based on "lowmem" and give a non-zero result, shouldn't they?

Comment: @user3528438: I presume that when you have more than 8GB of memory, all your free or reclaimable memory ends up being in highmem (partially because of the additional lowmem used by the page tables for the linear kernel mapping).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug in the kernel

According to the article you quoted, this is a bug, which did not exist in earlier kernels, and is fixed in more recent kernels.

> Note that this issue seems to be fixed in later releases (3.5.0+) and is a regression (doesn’t happen on e.g. 2.6.32)